# Make a UITableView "sticky to the bottom"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Say you have a table view T which shows messages,

```
T[ message d
T[ message c
T[ message b
T[ most recent message down bottom
```

Say there are 100 messages, with the bottom 4 visible in the example.

So the table view height is 700 say.  You have a typical text entry underneath...

```
T[ message d
T[ message c
T[ message b
T[ most recent message down bottom
[enter snapped chat message!] [send]
```

When the keyboard appears, the new height of the visible table view is 400 say.

Of course, that will "cut off the bottom" of the messages - the most recent two will no longer be visible.

```
T[ message d
T[ message c
[enter snapped chat message!] [send]
[           iOS keyboard        ]
[           iOS keyboard        ]
```

(So, messages A and B are now "under" the keyboard.)

Naturally what you do is just scroll the table after the keyboard appears, for example.  No problem doing it in an ad-hoc manner.

However, it would be really natural **if one could subclass UITableView in such a way that, as the size of the visible area changed, the table view knew to keep the "bottom point" identical**.

So, as the bottom of the table moves up and down (due to keyboard appearing - or whatever cause), the table would scroll actually based on the movement of the "base" of the table.

(Apart from anything else this would solve the "match the animation timing" nuisance.)

Could this be achieved elegantly and if so how - indeed this would seem so natural these days, perhaps it's built-in to UITableView as a flag and I just don't know?

once again the question here is

## How to modify UITableView so that it moves its own scroll position, as, the view size changes...

(so as to keep the "bottom point the same")

Note that it's trivial to just scroll the table "manually" as it were from the outside.

Comment: It's fascinating that there is simply **no way to do this**.  There is the astounding "trick" by mag_zbc which makes it happen (awesome).  But there's simply no natural way to do it in iOS, oddly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section headers stick to the top, so maybe something like this:
1. Make the most recent message a section header view instead of a table cell
2. Mirror the table view vertically:
`tableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1);`
3. Mirror vertically the section header and table cells
4. Reverse the order of your messages

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Dude the idea of ***mirroring the view*** is today's most boldest idea!  holy crap man!!!!!!

Comment: Note that you wouldn't have to do anything with sections (I think).  It would just keep the "top" at the "top" naturally (I think !)  holy crap!

Comment: This is the best way of achieving this, and there is a library that does all the work out of the box : https://github.com/marty-suzuki/ReverseExtension

Comment: @Dean - absolutely amazing !

Answer (score 2):

This is a *way* late answer, but I just solved the problem a bit more elegantly than the very ingenious accepted solution.

You'll need to have the following AutoLayout constraints (I'll omit the horizontal constraints):

- UITableView.top = Safe Area.top
- UITableView.bottom = MessageContainerView.top
- MessageContainerView.bottom = Safe Area.bottom

`MessageContainerView` is where I keep the message text view and button. Now, in your `ViewController` add an `IBOutlet` for the bottom constraint of `MessageContainerView`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var messageContainerBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Next step is animating the bottom constraint's constant to be equal to the keyboard height + the safe area at the bottom and scrolling the table to the bottom when the keyboard is shown (add an observer for the notification as well):

```
@objc func showKeyboard(_ notification: NSNotification) {
  guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
    let targetFrame = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue,
    let animationTime = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double
    else {
      return
  }

  let safeAreaBottom = view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
  messageContainerBottomConstraint.constant = -targetFrame.cgRectValue.height + safeAreaBottom
  UIView.animate(withDuration: animationTime) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.tableView.scrollToBottom()
  }
}
```

Note that we use `UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` for the animation timing, so everything will be smooth.

Lastly, `tableView.scrollToBottom()` is an Extension for `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit

extension UITableView {
  func scrollToBottom() {
    let numberOfSections = self.numberOfSections
    let numberOfRowsInSection = self.numberOfRows(inSection: numberOfSections - 1)
    let indexPathForLastRow = IndexPath(row: numberOfRowsInSection - 1, section: numberOfSections - 1)
    self.scrollToRow(at: indexPathForLastRow, at: .bottom, animated: false)
  }
}
```

Let me know if you can try it, and if I missed anything.

(I did notice you asked for a way to modify the native `UITableView` behavior instead of "manually" scrolling, but I think this is a valid way of solving the problem)

Comment: it's a fantastic answer.  I'll send a bounty since one is already chosen !

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have a few choices for doing this:

If you have the indexPath of the row you want to be visible:

```
tableView.ScrollToRow(indexPath, UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, true);
```

This will scroll to the cell given by the indexPath. In this case you are  selecting the option to show it on the `.Top` of the screen.

If you don't have the indexPath, you can use:

```
tableView.ScrollRectToVisible(new RectangleF(0, Ydisplacement, tableView.Width, tableView.Height), true);
```

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear.  Of course it's trivial to manually scroll a table.  What we want to do here is **subclass UITableView, so that, as the view resizes, the table view on its own exactly moves the table so that the "bottom point" completely matches at all times, even during the animation.**

Comment: Note that it says in the question "Naturally what you do is just scroll the table after the keyboard appears, for example. No problem doing it in an ad-hoc manner."  Note FTR that you can't really do that just using index path, you need the exact pixel position.  But it's unrelated to this question, cheers

Comment: Oh, you are right, I misread your question. Have you tried playing with autoLayout? I guess you would have to add a constraint to your tableView programmatically when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Hey bud - right, you'd surely have the .tableView view resize using autolayout.  the problem here however, is subclassing the SOB tableView, so that, it "knows" the view holding it is changing shape, and on its own accord it keeps the "bottom" (of the scroll) in the same place.